# How to get static member of platform specific code in shared code using DependencyService in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection

I am implementing MediaPicker Service that picks multiple files at once. Everything is working fine, when I use `LoadApplication(new App(MultiMediaPickerService.SharedInstance));` I use this to initialize `IMultiMediaPickerService`s in my shared code.

But I want to use Dependency Service to initialize and invoke methods in platform specific code.

Inshort, currently I am passing an object in `LoadApplication(new App(SharedInstance))` to my shared project. `SharedInstance` is a static object of `MultiMediaPickerService`. Hence, instance is passed on to the shared project. But I want to do it using **Dependency Service**.

**Here's my Interface IMultiMediaPickerService in shared project:**

```cs
public interface IMultiMediaPickerService
{
    event EventHandler<MediaFile> OnMediaPicked;
    ...
}
```

**MultiMediaPickerService in platform project (Android):**

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyProject.Droid.MultiMediaPickerService))]
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class MultiMediaPickerService : IMultiMediaPickerService
    {
        public static MultiMediaPickerService SharedInstance = new MultiMediaPickerService();
        ...
    }
}
```

**MainActivity in platform project (Android):**

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    LoadApplication(new App(MultiMediaPickerService.SharedInstance));
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    MultiMediaPickerService.SharedInstance.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I access the `MultiMediaPickerService.SharedInstance` from my shared project using the above method. But I want to access it using DependencyService just like:

```cs
var multiMediaPickerService = DependencySevice.Get<IMultiMediaPickerService>();
multiMediaPickerService.OnMediaPicked += (s, a) => { Debug.WriteLine("Media Picked"); };
```

As this is creating another instance, I am not getting the static object `MultiMediaPickerService.SharedInstance`. How it can be done? How can I access static member of the platform code from shared project using DependencyService?

Comment: `DependencyService` supports registering classes as singletons

Comment: @Jason - just looked at XF's DependencyService's API. Oddly, it lacks `RegisterSingleton<T,Timpl>();`. Only has `RegisterSingleton<T>();`. There doesn't seem to be a way to define platform-specific singleton of an interface. Puzzling.

Comment: FWIW: Not an answer to your question, but I find the current trend to make everything DI and totally hands-off to be overkill. I define `public static class Svc` accessible everywhere. Then have platform code set static properties. So `.. Svc { public static IMultiMediaPickerService MMPicker { get; set; } }`, set by `Svc.MMPicker = ...;`. Usage: `Svc.MMPicker.blahblahblah`. No need to scatter `DependencyService.get` everywhere, for simple situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you want can be done without any static members. All you should need is to register an instance of the `IMultiMediaPickerService` as a singleton in DependencyService.

IMultiMediaPickerService.cs

```cs
public interface IMultiMediaPickerService
{
    ...
}
```

MultiMediaPickerService.cs (Android implementation)

```cs
//[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyProject.Droid.MultiMediaPickerService))] <-- remove this
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
    public class MultiMediaPickerService : IMultiMediaPickerService
    {
        ...
        //no static shared instance here
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    //register an instance of MultiMediaPickerService as a singleton, the same instance will be returned whenever you ask for it using DependencySevice.Get<T>. Effectively, this gives you a shared instance without using static members
    var multiMediaPickerService = new MultiMediaPickerService();
    DependencyService.RegisterSingleton<IMultiMediaPickerService>(multiMediaPickerService);
    //use the instance to initialize the app
    LoadApplication(new App(multiMediaPickerService));
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //whenever using the IMultiMediaPickerService, get it using the DependencyService.Get<T> method
    var multiMediaPickerService = DependencyService.Get<IMultiMediaPickerService>();
    multiMediaPickerService.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Usage

```cs
//whenever using the IMultiMediaPickerService, get it using the DependencyService.Get<T> method
var multiMediaPickerService = DependencySevice.Get<IMultiMediaPickerService>();
multiMediaPickerService.OnMediaPicked += (s, a) => { Debug.WriteLine("Media Picked"); };
```